# C# The best overloaded method match for ...has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public class RegistrationClass
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MOE-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db_University;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
    ConnectionClass con = new ConnectionClass();
    int ID , i;
    String fullName, motherName, gender, placeOfBirth, email, phone, adress, schoolDegree, languages, highSchool, faculty, major;

    public void setValues (String fullName1,String motherName1,String gender1,String placeOfBirth1,String email1,String phone1,String adress1, String faculty1,String major1,String schoolDegree1,String languages1,String highSchool1)
    {
        fullName = fullName1;
        motherName = motherName1;
        gender = gender1;
        placeOfBirth= placeOfBirth1;
        email =email1;
        phone= phone1;
        adress =adress1;
        faculty =faculty1;
        major =major1;
        schoolDegree =schoolDegree1;
        languages =languages1;
        highSchool = highSchool1;
    }
```

This is the webform on register button click

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Button_Register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string lang = "";
        Classes.RegistrationClass R = new Classes.RegistrationClass();
        R.setValues(txt_Name.ToString, txt_MotherName.ToString, dropDown_Gender.ToString, dropDown_POB.ToString, txt_Email.ToString, txt_Phone.ToString, txt_Adress.ToString, DropDown_Faculty.ToString, DropDown_Major.ToString, dropDown_SchoolDegree.ToString, txt_Name.ToString, txt_HighSchool.ToString);
```

Here is the error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'CCharpApp.RegistrationClass.setValues(string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string)' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't have functions with so many arguments.

Comment: This method needs some TLC.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`txt_Name.ToString` resolves to a method group that refers to the `ToString` method.  It doesn't *call* `ToString`.  To do that you would need to write `txt_Name.ToString()`.  Having said that, you don't want to do that either.  The `ToString` method of `TextBox` does not return the text of the control.  The `Text` property is how you get the text, so you want to write: `txt_Name.Text`.

Finally, you should avoid functions with so many arguments.  It makes it much harder to try to determine what's wrong when you have the error that you are seeing when there are so many arguments; there are just so many ways that it could be off.  Instead `RegistrationClass` should simply have properties of each of those values, and then the caller can set each property individually.  This will be quite a lot easier to work with.

Comment: How does the application even compile when method group is passed instead of a String?

Comment: @Loreno It...doesn't...that's why the OP posted the compiler error generated.

Answer (score 37):

This can also happen when a `dynamic` variable is passed into the method as an argument. The compiler compiles without an error, there can be an execution error.

Comment: Yes, thanks for sharing, Martin. (DynamicObject, dynamic var)

Comment: Similar error occured to my, in my case the type was var

Comment: It appeared to be same on one of my case too.

Answer (score -1):

i had a same issue, solved as following.

```
dynamic postdata = new ExpandoObject();
postdata.player_name = player;
postdata.bidder_id = bidder;
postdata.bid_price = price;
postdata.status = "Sold";
```